# How to remove mount point on OS X (Catalina)?

Tags: macos, mount

I mounted an ext4 sd card like

```
brew cask install osxfuse
brew install ext4fuse
sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk2s2 ~/mp2
```

After unmounting it with

```
sudo umount ~/mp2
```

I still see it with `ls -ls`:

```
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root       staff    64 14 Dez 14:49 mp2
```

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a directory now with nothing mounted in it.

```
rmdir ~/mp2
```